# clearing the tabs when pasting from visual studio

Tags: support

I often want to paste code from visual studio and find that I have too much of a left margin

As my question [here does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832424/how-do-i-make-ef-entitytype-getproperty-eager-load)

Is there an easy way to correct the left margin to take up less space?

Comment: Not on the SO side AFAIK. I unindent it in the IDE before copying (e.g with Shift + tab)

Comment: `Ctrl+K` in the SO editor will dedent a code block if all of its lines share the same amount of "extra" indentation.

Comment: Didn't realise that. I've only ever used it for adding indentation to non indented code.

Comment: I just fixed it with Ctrl+K @FrédéricHamidi please put this as the answer

Comment: If you hold the Alt key down when selecting in VS, you get block-select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested I will expand on my comment.

In the site's editor, selecting a code block then:

- clicking the "Code Sample" `{}` button, or
- hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Will dedent the block by one level if all of its lines share the same amount of "extra" indentation.